# Filter data in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to make an application which tries to find the trending stocks in the last 6 months. The application checks for two conditions namely:

1. Is (previous close) < (close) If yes then True is returned
2. Else false is returned.

After determining the above two conditions the  programme checks how many true values are there in succession if there are multiple true values add 1 to the Trending Counter and append it as a column. For false values counter has to be set as 0.

The code for the same is:

```
import pandas as pd
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
import sqlalchemy
import numpy as np
stock = ['APLAPOLLO','AUBANK','AARTIDRUGS']
res = dict(zip(stock,stock))
start = date (2020, 6, 14)
end = date (2020, 12, 15)

for stock_name in stock:
     data = get_history(symbol=stock_name, start=start, end=end)
     res[stock_name]=data
for key, df in res.items():
     # create a column called "key name"
     df['key_name'] = key

lst = list(res.values())
df = pd.concat(lst)
df['boolean'] = df['Prev Close'] < df['Close']

a = df['boolean']
b = a.cumsum()
df['trend'] = (b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)).where(a, 0)
```

The resulting DataFrame is as shown:

[image: Dataframe]

**I want to change one of the condition as: For a given symbol even if one value is encountered as false assign 0 for all the following values in the trend column for that particular symbol.**

eg: On 15/6/2020 For APLAPOLLO the boolean value is false hence in the given dataframe I want to set the trend value of APLAPOLLO as 0 for all the rows after that particular row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can create numbered groups of False entries - the True entries will be NaN, then forward fill to fill in True entries that occur after False entries.    Then just fill your early True values with a sentinel value
df["trend"].fillna(value=1, inplace=True) and use where to fill everything except your sentinels with 0.

This approach is easily adapted to a number of different problems relating to trends that have a boolean component.

Here's working code - you can split the lines and print out the data at each step if you want to be sure you know how this works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'boolean': [True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True]})
# set the condition
trendBasis = ~df['boolean']
# Create numbered groups of False entries - True entries will be NaN
df["trend"] = (~trendBasis).cumsum().where(trendBasis)
#Forward fill to fill in True entries that occur after False entries
df["trend"].fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)
#Fill your early True values with a sentinel value
df["trend"].fillna(value=1, inplace=True)
#Use where to fill everything except your sentinels with 0
df["trend"] = df["trend"].where(df["trend"]==1, 0)
#Profit!
print(df)

    boolean  trend
0      True    1.0
1      True    1.0
2      True    1.0
3      True    1.0
4     False    0.0
5     False    0.0
6      True    0.0
7      True    0.0
8     False    0.0
9      True    0.0
10    False    0.0
11     True    0.0
​
```